# What is the string length of a default .NET CORE password hash?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

I've been trying to find info on this for some time and it doesn't seem as easy as I would have thought, I've found the source code of the [default Hasher](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore/blob/main/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/PasswordHasher.cs) , but it has many hashing methods and the output there has some formatting done to it and as I understand it, the salt is contained within it. I don't work with byte types, so the code is a bit confusing to me.

The reason I even need this is to set up the data type in my database. Currently I have it at char(64). I'm saving it as a string representation, because that's what a lot of the methods in .net Identity use anyway.

Comment: If tells you right there in the source code you referenced. The V2 hash, for example, is `Format: { 0x00, salt, subkey }` with `128-bit salt` and `256-bit subkey` so `1 + (128/8) + (256/8) = 1 + 16 + 32 = 49 bytes`. The binary hash is then base64 encoded which causes it to expand from 49 bytes to 68 characters. Calculating the length of a V3 is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I'm lazy (which I think is positive). I just set a datatype that is 'big enough' in the database, then store some values an check the length.

Comment: @PoulBak What kind of "big enough" values are you using? Provided it's not `nvarchar(4000)`... Also, remember that more and more RDMBS have deprecated `varchar(n)` types, like Postgres, and use `text` (which is _not_ a LOB type in Postgres, unlike in SQL Server), limits on length are set using a `CHECK` constraint - which makes more sense to me.

Comment: @Dai: The OP does not mention, which database, but yes, I would use `varchar` or `varbinary` in MySql. As I said, I'm lazy  :)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Ok it's the 49 bytes to 68 that was most confusing to me, but an answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452184/understanding-tobase64string) question helped. Basically you divide by 3, round up, multiply by 4. But I'm also confused as to where that 1 byte at the start came from, is it the one that represents the "0x00"? Anyway I think I'm gonna set it "big enough" too, in case something changes in the future, maybe 128 characters.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.